# pandas: reorder pivot table columns to an arbitrary order

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pivot table that looks like the following:

```
                             completed_olns                  total_completed_olns
work_type                             A     B          C                     
employee                                                                     
Employee1                            94  1163          1                 1258
Employee2                           168   770          4                  942
Employee3                           173   746          8                  927
```

How can I rearrange the columns A, B, C to an arbitrary order, such as  B, A, C?

This data is being output from a database and read in through csv with  `pd.read_csv()`

I've tried `pivot.sort_index(level=1, axis=1, ascending=False)` which gets me closer but not to what I need.

I've also tried `pivot = pivot[['B', 'A', 'C']]` which gives me:

`KeyError: "['B', 'A', 'C'] not in index"`

These are the two most common suggestions that I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.reindex` with the `level` argument

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(1,10,(3,6)))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['collected', 'total_collected'], ['A','B','C']])
#  collected       total_collected      
#          A  B  C               A  B  C
#0         2  6  9               9  6  6
#1         5  4  4               5  2  6
#2         8  9  3               9  2  7
```

#### Code

```
df.reindex(axis=1, level=1, labels=['B', 'A', 'C'])
#  collected       total_collected      
#          B  A  C               B  A  C
#0         6  2  9               6  9  6
#1         4  5  4               2  5  6
#2         9  8  3               2  9  7
```

With groups missing labels or labels that never exist, it won't insert all `NaN` columns

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].reindex(axis=1, level=1, labels=['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'])
#  collected       total_collected   
#          B  A  C               B  A
#0         6  2  9               6  9
#1         4  5  4               2  5
#2         9  8  3               2  9
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for.